# Using two slicers to set a numeric range

Tags: powerbi, slicers

I have a column in my dataset which refers to the Quarter, set up as YYYYQ (ex: 20212 for Q2-2021) and I want to be able to use slicers to filter the data to a range of quarters.  The Built-In range slicer is functional, but the slider includes quarters which do not exist (ex. 20216, there is no 6th Quarter in 2021).

Is there a way to use two separate dropdown slicers to set a range for the quarters, and calculate values within that range?

Answer (score 1):

1. Derive from your clumsy "quarter number" a *First of Quarter* date (calculated column)

```
First of Quarter = 
VAR STR = 
    CONVERT('Table'[Quarter], STRING)
RETURN
    DATE(LEFT(STR, 4), 1 + (RIGHT(STR) - 1) * 3, 1)
```

2. *Get more visuals* from the market place and import Microsoft's **Timeline Slicer** into your report
3. Add the Timeline Slicer to your page using the above *First of Quarter* date and select quarterly resolution.

The result will look something like this and will give you the slicer experience you are looking for:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this isn't really what I'm looking for.  I'm looking for a way to have a dropdown slicer set the lower end of the range, and a second dropdown slicer set the upper limit.  I'm not sure how to set up the DAX for any affected measures.